# How can I pre-populate a new Google Calendar event?

Tags: google-calendar-api, autohotkey

My son uses Google Calendar for his roster (layer2) and homework (layer1).

When a new event is manually added to the Google Calendar, I want to pre-populate the event text, to remind him not to skip important data.

So when he clicks on the calendar to add a NEW event (existing events should not be modified) the text field should already say:

Subj:   Chapter:    Page:

I have tried to use AutoHotKey, but the "New event" window is not detected by the AutoHotKey spy.

In the Google scripts, I have not been able to find a function like OnOpenNewEvent, to launch a script at the moment a new event window is opened.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new event window is just HTML, so no--it isn't a new window, and AHK can't detect it.

It looks like event templates are a commonly-requested feature, but I haven't found any ideas on how to do it.

A couple alternative suggestions:

- Put together a script that monitors the RSS/ical feed for his calendar, and looks for events that are missing the desired tags;  then take some action when the tags are missing
- Make an autohotkey script that detects a series of keystrokes, and inserts the template.  For example, when he types ".hw." in a google chrome window or firefox window, it will generate the template.  See script below:

> ```
> #ifWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_0
> :C:.hw.::Subj: Chapter: Page:
> #ifWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
> :C:.hw.::Subj: Chapter: Page:
> #ifWinActive
> ```

The above script requires teaching him to type the template text ".hw.", but at least remembering one thing is easier than three.

Comment: Kimball, Thank you for your suggestions, I will try them and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Kimball,

Based on your initial thought, I have opted to (initially) use the following:

```
:c*:qq::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinActive, Google Calendar - Google Chrome
{
    Send, Subj:  Chapt:  Page:{space}
    Send, {Home}
    Send, {right 6}
}
Else
{
    Send, qq
}
Return
```

This way the hotstring "qq" is always executed, unlike your approach, but only expanded when the calendar is open in Chrome. I opted for the *, so the hotstring is executed immediately.

I learned something new from your approach, setting a hotstring dynamically depending on the winActive status. I will start to play with that idea...

Do you know which method, yours v.s. mine is more efficient? Maybe there is no real difference in the end.

And yes, I know I could combine all Send lines into one if I wanted to.